# Basic Websocket-Example for Jetty 9

Tags: websocket, jetty

I'm trying to make a real basic Websocket example work on standalone Jetty, but i'm stuck on a NullPointerException.

Here are my 2 server classes:

```java
@WebServlet("/MyWebSocketServlet")
public class MyWebSocketServlet extends WebSocketServlet {

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSocketServletFactory factory) {
        factory.register(MyWebSocket.class);
    }
}
```

```java
@WebSocket
public class MyWebSocket{

    @OnWebSocketConnect
    public void onConnect(Session session){
        System.out.println("MyWebSocket.onConnect()");
    }

    @OnWebSocketMessage
    public void onText(String msg) {
        System.out.println("MyWebSocket.onText()");
    }

    @OnWebSocketClose
    public void onClose(int statusCode, String reason) {
        System.out.println("MyWebSocket.onClose()");
    } 
}
```

I try to establish communication through JavaScript in Chrome:

```xml
<script type="text/javascript">
    var echoSocket = new WebSocket(
        "ws://localhost:8080/JettyWebsocketsTest/MyWebSocketServlet"
    );

    echoSocket.onopen = function(e) {
        console.log("onopen()");
        echoSocket.send("Hello");
    }

    echoSocket.onmessage = function(e) {
        console.log("msg received");
    };
</script>
```

Unfortunately the connection won't establish and instead this NullPointerException is thrown:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketServerFactory.upgrade(WebSocketServerFactory.java:400)
at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketServerFactory.acceptWebSocket(WebSocketServerFactory.java:168)
at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.servlet.WebSocketServlet.service(WebSocketServlet.java:160)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:558)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:489)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:520)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:233)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:972)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:417)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:192)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:906)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:110)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:350)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:442)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:910)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:565)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:217)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:46)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:545)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:43)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:598)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:533)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

These lines in WebSocketServerFactory throw that Exception:

```java
HttpConnection http = HttpConnection.getCurrentConnection();
EndPoint endp = http.getEndPoint();
```

What can i do for an available HttpConnection?

Comment: If you use the test webapp's websocket chat in the jetty-distribution, does it work for you?   The NPE you are seeing from HttpConnection.getCurrentConnection() is troublesome (as that shouldn't be possible) and I'd like your help to narrow down the cause.

Comment: When i got this error i was using the run-jetty-run eclipse plugin.  Now as i copied my project to the webapps-folder manually it works. As there is no WTP adapter for Jetty 9 available: How do you develop and debug for Jetty? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What version of Jetty? and what version of run-jetty-run are you using?  I would like to try to replicate.

Comment: And for the record, I only use embedded jetty (from unit tests and test classes) to develop and debug for jetty.

Comment: jetty-distribution-9.0.2.v20130417 and run-jetty-run 1.3.2. I realized later that there is a newer version 1.3.3 available. The naming during the eclipse installation is misleading. Anyway it started Jetty and i could invoke normal servlets so i somewhat forgot that this could be the cause of trouble.

Comment: hmmm... but maybe it started another jetty and not my 9.0.2 ??? I'll switch to embedded jetty...